# eclipse issue with .pack files

Tags: eclipse, pack

I purchased some code made in build box and when I look at, it has .pack files which show up as gibberish text in Eclipse. I read about changing file names to .txt and.zip but that did not fix anything. Could not open as .zip with 7zip, and when .txt it was still gibberish text.

What am I missing to be able to read this file type with Eclipse?

Comment: It is clearly a binary file, not text. Eclipse will not be able to make sense of this (unless there is a plug-in that understands the binary format).

Comment: I understand that, and when it was explained to me before I thought it would be a .xml file type which would be easy to work with.